# Is it correct to say "Your clothes will dry out soon" or "Your clothes will dry off soon"?

Tags: word-usage, word-choice, phrase-usage, phrase-choice

Some native speakers say

-"**dry off**" if the water is on a surface of an object and is not licking into that object

-"**dry out**" if the water is licking into that object

So, if water is on a object, the object will dry off

if water is in a object, the object will dry out

For example, "**dry off your body after a shower**" because water doesn't lick into our body

but "**hang out the sponge to dry it out**" because the water lick into the sponge.

Do we strictly use "**dry off**" and "**dry out**" that way? or it doesn't matter?

Is it correct to say "**Your clothes will dry out soon**" or "**Your clothes will dry off soon**"?

Comment: Soaking, not licking.

Comment: Yes, I would certainly say that clothes need to dry **out**, unless perhaps the person was wearing something minimal such as a swimsuit.